# CSS code helped center images, but it somehow reverted back to left side with current coding

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser, safari

Previously I did this:

```
#navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width:400px;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

But somehow my images reverted back to the left side completely. 
This also only happens in Firefox and not safari! What should I do?

Comment: on S.O try to give a screenshot (or an image link at least), or something similar to elaborate your problem.

Comment: I can't add images here yet

Comment: Nothing you have here should cause that problem. Probably something else.  Can you link to a page or create a fiddle to illustrate the problem?

Comment: I know by seeing your repo score, but you can give their link by uploading them on FB and making their privacy to 'Only me'.
At last provide a better explanation.

Comment: okay, it is here http://postimg.org/image/ctmsmpuoj/ I'm trying to align it with the text nav bar. It looks like that in firefox only. should i maybe edit the html files or just the css file?

Comment: But the img is inside the ul?? can you paste the specific html and css for the image?

Comment: <div id="homepage" class="container">
   <div class="span-24 last">
  <div id="header" class="span-24 last">
   <a href="index.html"><img src="header.gif"></a>
  </div>

Comment: the css is another file separate from each of my page's html. its a .css file that i upload onto filezilla

Comment: you are trying to center a ul?

Comment: should i not be? this current code was actually amended to help me center the images, it worked until now. it still works in safari, but firefox is showing my images at the left

Comment: but where the hell is #navigation ul ??? i don't see it

Comment: my navigation ul code is in another file called cssfile.css

Comment: nop no that in the html you don't have any ul or id="navigation"

Comment: #navigation ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
width:400px;
margin:auto;text-align: center;}

#navigation li {
margin: 1em 1em;
font-family: Times New Roman, Times, Calibri, GillSans, sans-serif;
font-style: italic;
display: inline-block;}

#navigation li a {
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
}

Comment: no, no ul, navigation in my html files at all

Comment: Try making it display:block

Comment: for both? li and li a?

Comment: Can you paste the link to your page?

Comment: Seriously, paste the link to your actual page with the actual navigation text.  You're not getting what we're trying to say, and we can't help you without seeing what actually is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accordly to your page you have this structure:

```
<div id="content" class="span-24 last">
  <center><img src="front.jpg"></center>
</div>
```

First at all you don't need the `<center>` tag. And second you need this on your CSS:

```
#content {
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:25px; /*to keep the value you have just for top*/
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: i'm not sure if you saw my comment but it got erased, i tried that code, it brought my page content all the way up but the image is still on the left

Comment: can you give a link to your page? then i can see where the problem is

Comment: thanks for the help, but its still the same and now it doesn't work on safari too :(

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR HELPING ME OUT AGAIN @DANKO, REALLY APPRECIATE THIS!

Comment: Np mate glad to help you